# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returning nil all the time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know this post is maybe triplicate or so, but none of the answers on existing threads helped me so far.

I'm trying to get NSDate value from string, but I'm constantly getting nil as a result. This is my code

```
NSString * dateString = cell.lblAlertDate.text;//this value is "06/11/2013 23:55" for example
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mi"];

self.selectedAlarmDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
```

what is the `i` doing there …

Comment: "mi" was there because my background is not in objective-c, and in C# that format should be fine, I think so. It seems like my mindset is still in C# mode:D

Comment: Haha, got a downvote on this. Nevermind, it was worth it. Accepting this answer in 5 minutes (SO does not let me do so earlier)

Comment: I guess, it will not only be down voted but also deleted. but nevermind.